# sinon.match appears undefined, missing right file?

Tags: javascript, testing, sinon

I was trying to use `sinon.match` but noticed that the [download link from the sinon site](http://sinonjs.org/releases/sinon-1.3.4.js) doesn't appear to have `match` in it.

http://jsfiddle.net/GccH5/

Then I tried to include `match` from lib from the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/cjohansen/Sinon.JS):

http://jsfiddle.net/GccH5/1/

It then complains: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'typeOf'`.

I tried using GitHub's sinon:

http://jsfiddle.net/GccH5/2/

But now, it appears I need to include spies, stubs etc myself? How can I just compile everything into 1 minified file for example? Or whats the recommended way of using sinon? I think it might be through node/npm/require ... but I am not using them at work ... :(

Answer (score 0):

[It seems](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/sinonjs/gB49z4RkvKI) the documentation was published early for the next release by accident. You can download a preview version from here http://sinonjs.org/releases/sinon-next.js or if you are using node you can download the [master source from github](https://github.com/cjohansen/Sinon.JS/downloads) and copy it inside your node_modules folder.

I have a fairly large test suite that I tested both on, and am yet to have anything go wrong.